# bash returns different results when commands are passed to bash shell via ssh or HEREDOC

Tags: bash, ssh, heredoc

I have a directory that looks something like this:

```
$:ls /home/my-folder*

/home/my-folder1
/home/my-folder2
/home/my-folder3
```

When I try sending this via ssh to myself it does this:
    $:ssh user@server.com "for x in /home/my-folder*;do echo $x; done"

```
/home/my-folder3
/home/my-folder3
/home/my-folder3
```

when I use this commands it returns

```
$:for x in /home/my-folder*;
do echo $x
done

/home/my-folder1
/home/my-folder2
/home/my-folder3
```

I can reproduce the results by pass a HEREDOC from the interactive shell to bash

```
$:bash <<EOF
for x in /home/my-folder*;
do echo $x
done 
EOF

/home/my-folder3
/home/my-folder3
/home/my-folder3
```

But when I use a subshell it works

```
echo $(for x in /uufs/chpc.utah.edu/common/home/$group-group*;do echo $x; done)
/home/my-folder1 /home/my-folder2 /home/my-folder3
```

Comment: that code (with the `$(for ...; done)`) isn't reliable in any circumstances. Try filenames with spaces or wildcard characters in them.

Comment: Anyhow, the thing about heredocs is that they're evaluated **locally**, **before** `ssh` is started, unless you quote the sigil (`<<'EOF'`, not plain `<<EOF`). We have duplicates in the knowledgebase already describing this; I'll try to find one.

Comment: In this code `ssh user@server.com "for x in /home/my-folder*;do echo $x; done"` the variable `$x` is evaluated *before* the `ssh` command is called, thus it will *not* get the value of `x` in the for loop. Same issue with the HEREDOC of `<<EOF`. You can fix this by quoting the EOF: `bash <<'EOF'`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, I wasn't sure where the variables were being evaluated, but I didn't even think about how the * was being evaluted.

Comment: The wildcard is remote even with an unquoted heredoc; it's just parameter expansions, command substitutions and the like that are evaluated early. Of course, if you put a wildcard expansion *in* a command substitution in an unquoted heredoc, that makes it local.

Comment: Wow, This is me really dropping the ball. Should have noticed I needed to escape the $x.